# New RAMPS 1.6 not working

Tags: diy-3d-printer, arduino-mega-2650, ramps-1.6

I just bought a new RAMPS 1.6 shield to replace my old RAMPS 1.4 shield. The problem is that it's just not working, the motors don't move, heatbed/nozzle don't get heated. It was all working with the RAMPS 1.4 shield.

I checked the RAMPS 1.6 and there's no bridging in the solder joints.

The DRV8255 is drawing current also but the motor doesn't move.

I am using Repetier Firmware. I tried Marlin (default) and even it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So In my case, the RAMPS were defective, I returned them and got a new replacement from Amazon. The new one worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Pins are sometimes different between the two shields.  I ran into one a while back... Go over the pin specs for the 1.6 one at a time.

Correction: pins are SUPPOSED to be the same.  I've however experienced them not being the same.  I don't know if my 1.3s were the oddballs or if the 1.6 was.

Comment: My RAMPS 1.6 is exactly the same to a RAMPS 1.4, I used the 1.4 pin layout without a problem. The 1.6 is only a hardware upgrade with respect to connectors, fuses and MOSFETs and heatsink. I looked up the original source from the manufacturer, it also refers to RAMPS 1.3/1.4, so, there should be no pin changes. If there were such changes, there should be a separate pins header file for the 1.6, but I cannot find such a file. Please do explain the differences you found, the answer could use some more in depth information.

Comment: As well as the differences, please state the brand/model of the boards, plus a photo if possible. There may be a particular manufacturer who is not adhering to the standard.

Comment: If I still had the board, I might be able to share.  I believe it was around the end of 2018? after running out of 1.3s and still needing one more in a hurry.  I just remember not finding a quick pin list and thinking I could have saved myself some trouble of tracing if I had paid attention to the labels on the board.